# Python - An "if" statement if an exception occurs

Tags: python, exception, if-statement

I want an if statement to occur once an exception goes off. What is the function for that, or is it even possible?

This is what I'm trying to get

```
try:
    save_this_number_file(s)
except:
    print("could not find file. Don't forget to add *.txt* to the end of file name.")
    if (except):
        again = input("Would you like to try again? (y/n) ")
        if (again != 'y'):
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: If you are in the except block the Exception has already occurred. Isn't that a sufficient condition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't need a conditional because if you are in the `except` block it means an exception has occurred

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Anything in the `except` routine is *only* run if an exception occurs. Thus, you could just use:

```
try:
    save_this_number_file(s)
except:
    print("could not find file. Don't forget to add *.txt* to the end of file name.")
    again = input("Would you like to try again? (y/n) ")
    if (again != 'y'):
        sys.exit()
```

If you want to run your code after something else happens, you can simply set a boolean that an exception occured.

By the way, you should try to say what exception you want to catch. If you don't, something like a KeyboardInterrupt (^C) could throw an exception and perhaps cause some harm. [More information on this can be found here.](http://effbot.org/zone/stupid-exceptions-keyboardinterrupt.htm)

Answer (score -1):

I found this here :http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm

```
try:    
You do your operations here;
except:
If there is any exception, then execute this block.    
else:    
If there is no exception then execute this block.

try:
   fh = open("testfile", "w")
   fh.write("This is my test file for exception handling!!")
except IOError:
   print "Error: can\'t find file or read data"
else:
   print "Written content in the file successfully"
   fh.close()
```